# Update Data Extension Field to NULL using WSProxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm trying out the new WSProxy API for server-side javascript. I haven't been able to update a Data Extension field to NULL when it already contains a value.

Let's say "Student" is a nullable field. Putting this into the `Properties` array passed to the `updateItem` method doesn't clear out a value already stored in the Data Extension:

```
{
    Name: 'Student',
    Value: null
}
```

Neither does leaving the `Value` property out entirely:

```
{
    Name: 'Student'
}
```

The SOAP API documentation makes reference to a `NullAPIProperty` object to use in this circumstance, but I can't figure out how to pass that kind of object to WSProxy or get that API to create it. (Creating an object using `Platform.Function.CreateObject()` throws an error; that's a different API).

Comment: have you tried `Value: ''`?

Comment: I verified that `''` as a Value works for boolean fields!

Text fields are set to a zero-length string, which is not the same as NULL. This is important when using the `IS NULL` operator and similar functions in SQL.

Comment: try `{ Name: 'Student', Value: }` - but I expect you will likely get a syntax error. I think the empty string may be the best you can do. Perhaps try putting in a support ticket to SFMC.  I will explore on my side as well and post if I find an answer

Comment: OH!  Try setting a SSJS var to null then put that var inside your WSProxy call.  `var iAmNull` or `var iAmNull = null` then `{ Value: iAmNull }` I get the feeling this may not work either, but worth exploring.

Answer (score 11):

There's a hidden feature of WSProxy to allow you to do this!

If you were to write the raw SOAP call to set the value of a field in your DE record to NULL, you'd write it like this:

```
       <Property xsi:type="NullAPIProperty">
          <Name>StoreNumber</Name>
       </Property>
```

Notice, there's no value, but there is a *type* attribute on the Property element.  You have to set that NullAPIProperty attribute on your property in the WSProxy call.  To do that, you use a special notation: `__Type__`

So, you'd write your null property like so:

```
{
    Name: 'Student',
    "__Type__": 'NullAPIProperty'
}
```

The attribute notation is unfortunately not currently documented, but I'll see if I can contact someone who can get it on the help site.