# Setting date to null with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Any good ideas for setting a date field to null using SSJS? I have tried:

```javascript
consents.Rows.Update({optinDate:now,optOutDate:''}, ['id'], [contactID]); //no luck
consents.Rows.Update({optinDate:now,optOutDate:null}, ['id'], [contactID]); //no luck
consents.Rows.Update({optinDate:now,optOutDate:}, ['id'], [contactID]); //error 500
```

The date field IS nullable, and has no default value set.

Comment: Here's the undocumented WSProxy method: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227615/5202

Comment: Thanks, @AdamSpriggs - there is a first time for everything. Also for closing your own question as duplicate :-)